# Laravel Vapor - Bus::chain does not work in order

Tags: laravel, chain, bus, laravel-vapor

We are using latest Vapor and latest Laravel version and we use Bus::chain([...]) method in order to run some asynchronous jobs in order.

For example, we have this use case, where these jobs must be processed in order to work correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srsDF.png)

We do have multiple workers on this specific queue and jobs do not run in order like it states in the docs. Some last job might start before first and second job is not finished.

Has anyone encountered this issue and maybe do you have recommendations how this should be fixed?

I expect Bus::chain to work in order.

Comment: What queue driver are you using?